# Xorg + fbdev driver (/etc/X11/xorg.conf）dosen't work in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, drivers, xorg, framebuffer

I need to use fbdev driver(framebuffer) in Xorg to get better system latency.

So I use "Xorg :1 -configure" to get the default xorg.conf file. Then change the "Device" part, and copy xorg.conf to /etc/X11. Reboot Ubuntu.

```
    /etc/X11/xorg.conf
    Section "Device"
         ### Available Driver options are:-
         ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
         ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
         ### <percent>: "<f>%"
         ### [arg]: arg optional
         #Option     "ShadowFB"             # [<bool>]
         #Option     "Rotate"               # <str>
         #Option     "fbdev"                # <str>
         #Option     "debug"                # [<bool>]
         Identifier  "Card0"
         #Driver     "vmware"
         Driver      "fbdev"
         BusID       "PCI:0:15:0"
    EndSection
```

In Ubuntu 16.04.6 , it works in this way. Sadly, in Ubuntu 18.04.4, it dosen't.

//Ubuntu 16.04.6

hust@hust-pc:~$ inxi -G

```
       Graphics:  Card: VMware SVGA II Adapter
       Display Server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: fbdev
       Resolution: 800x600@0.00hz
       GLX Renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 256 bits)
       GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 18.0.5
```

//Ubuntu 18.04.4

hust@hust-virtual-machine:~$ inxi -G

```
       Graphics:  Card: VMware SVGA II Adapter
       Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.5 ) drivers: vmware (unloaded: modesetting,fbdev,vesa)
       Resolution: 2880x1520@60.00hz
       OpenGL: renderer: SVGA3D; build version: 3.3 Mesa 19.2.8
```

I try to degrade the Xorg version in Ubuntu 18.04, but it causes the Xorg to hang sometimes.Then I try it in vmvare machine.

How can I change the Xorg driver to fbdev in Ubuntu 18.04?